# How do I remove text "by" and " | " from post meta in Divi?

Tags: wordpress, post-meta

[I want to remove these highlighted texts from meta section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yM8tT.png)

Comment: Why dont you post the same into the elegant support forum

Comment: they are not responding right away

Comment: Give me the support thread url to me, I will look after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please go to Divi >includes > builder > functions.php file and you can find the code there.

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'et_pb_postinfo_meta' ) ) :
function et_pb_postinfo_meta( $postinfo, $date_format, $comment_zero, $comment_one, $comment_more ){
    $postinfo_meta = '';

    if ( in_array( 'author', $postinfo ) )
        $postinfo_meta .= ' ' . esc_html__( 'by', 'et_builder' ) . ' <span class="author vcard">' . et_pb_get_the_author_posts_link() . '</span>';

    if ( in_array( 'date', $postinfo ) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'author', $postinfo ) ) $postinfo_meta .= ' | ';
        $postinfo_meta .= '<span class="published">' . esc_html( get_the_time( wp_unslash( $date_format ) ) ) . '</span>';
    }
```

Remove by and | from here > save and  check.

Comment: done! Thank you so much

Comment: Modifying anything in the Divi theme itself means that if you update the theme, your changes will go away. It's designed in such a way that you can literally copy/paste the `function et_pb_postinfo_meta(){ … }` function (without the `function_exists` check) straight into a child theme's `functions.php` file, or even a [Must Use Plugin](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/) to make sure your changes aren't overwritten by security updates

Comment: @Xhynk has posted the correct answer to this question in his comment. Don't edit Divi files. Use a child theme and override them so that you don't lose them when you update Divi.